# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SessionState

Tags: python, python-3.x, session-state, streamlit

I am trying to make use of the streamlit SessionState, when I import `SessionState`. I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SessionState'`
when using he SessionState

Here is a snipnet of my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import streamlit as st
import SessionState
import time
import os
import signal

st.sidebar.title("Controls")
start = st.sidebar.button("Start")
stop = st.sidebar.button("Stop")

state = SessionState.get(pid=None)
```

Has anyone encountered this and how did you fix it? There are no resources online

Comment: Can you show the code snippet that you're using the importing?

Comment: I just updated it. Can you check again?

Comment: where should the `SessionState` class come from - is it declared in your code or some dependency?

Comment: I think its some form of dependency from streamlit. but here is it: https://gist.github.com/tvst/036da038ab3e999a64497f42de966a92

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/changelog.html?highlight=SessionState#version-0-54-0

Seems like you have to download [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tvst/036da038ab3e999a64497f42de966a92) and put it into your project in order to use SessionState

Answer (score 0):

Session State is now natively supported in Streamlit via the 0.84.0 release!

```
pip install --upgrade streamlit
```